# iCloud Server Space Limitation for iOS Application

Tags: ios, icloud

This is general question,
Is there any limitation for application to store data on iCloud Server (Not exceed max Limit of 5 GB in general).

Comment: [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) says no general questions!

Comment: I found this question through google and found both the question and the answer useful - even if they are a bit general - so imho, this did not deserved to be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Design Considerations for iCloud Apps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iCloud/iCloud.html) ,See the section *Being a Responsible iCloud App*

> It clearly states : **Apps that take advantage of iCloud storage features should act responsibly when storing data there. The space available in each user’s account is limited and is shared by all apps. Users can see how much space is consumed by a given app and choose to delete documents and data associated with your app. For these reasons, it is in your app’s interest to be responsible about what files you store.**

and the above said limitation in general is 5GB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but there is nothing about storage limitation of particular application in iCloud.